# Access a .wav file from C++ Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm trying to read a .wav file that I have from my .cpp file that I have in my iOS Xcode project. I have searched and I can't find the answer to why it is not reading it well. I putted in all the possible directories and still doesn't work. This is the code that is calling the .wav file:

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
EXPORT
string getAudioWmark()
{
  
    std::string result;
    result = get_watermark("piano2.wav", "");
    
    return (result.c_str());
}
```

get_watermark method (from wget.cc):

```
std::string get_watermark (const string& infile, const string& orig_pattern)
{
    std::string patterns;
    WavData wav_data;
    Error err = wav_data.load (infile);
    if (err)
    {
        error ("audiowmark: error loading %s: %s\n", infile.c_str(), err.message());
        return "1";
    }

    if (Params::test_truncate)
    {
        const size_t  want_n_samples = wav_data.sample_rate() * wav_data.n_channels() * Params::test_truncate;
        vector<float> short_samples  = wav_data.samples();

        if (want_n_samples < short_samples.size())
        {
            short_samples.resize (want_n_samples);
            wav_data.set_samples (short_samples);
        }
    }

    int result;
    if (wav_data.sample_rate() == Params::mark_sample_rate)
    {
        result = decode_and_report (wav_data, orig_pattern);
        
        if (PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns() != "") {
            patterns = PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns();
        }

        return patterns;
    }
    else
    {
        result = decode_and_report (resample (wav_data, Params::mark_sample_rate), orig_pattern);
        
        if (PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns() != "") {
            patterns = PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns();
        }

        return patterns;
    }
}
```

Here is the directories from my Xcode project (the code above is from native-lib.cpp:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There has to be some sort of error reporting mechanism that will tell you what went wrong. Unfortunately my googling about for `get_watermark` come up with no useful hits.

Comment: The error is: audiowmark: error loading piano2.wav: System error : No such file or directory. I updated the question with the get_watemark method